# Cannot hyperlink an image in a slideshow for some reason

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript slideshow. I added to my page and it works great. I'm not a javascript developer and got the solution online. However I need each image to link somewhere and despite how simple it should be, I cannot get it to work. When I add a  tag the image disappears...can anyone help? Maybe add an additional config parameter to the javascript code where a URL could be entered?

```js
(function($) {
  "use strict";
  $.fn.sliderResponsive = function(settings) {

    var set = $.extend({
        slidePause: 5000,
        fadeSpeed: 800,
        autoPlay: "off",
        showArrows: "on",
        hideDots: "on",
        hoverZoom: "on",
        titleBarTop: "off"
      },
      settings
    );

    var $slider = $(this);
    var size = $slider.find("> div").length; //number of slides
    var position = 0; // current position of carousal
    var sliderIntervalID; // used to clear autoplay

    // Add a Dot for each slide
    $slider.append("<ul></ul>");
    $slider.find("> div").each(function() {
      $slider.find("> ul").append('<li></li>');
    });

    // Put .show on the first Slide
    $slider.find("div:first-of-type").addClass("show");

    // Put .showLi on the first dot
    $slider.find("li:first-of-type").addClass("showli")

    //fadeout all items except .show
    $slider.find("> div").not(".show").fadeOut();

    // If Autoplay is set to 'on' than start it
    if (set.autoPlay === "on") {
      startSlider();
    }

    // If showarrows is set to 'on' then don't hide them
    if (set.showArrows === "on") {
      $slider.addClass('showArrows');
    }

    // If hideDots is set to 'on' then hide them
    if (set.hideDots === "on") {
      $slider.addClass('hideDots');
    }

    // If hoverZoom is set to 'off' then stop it
    if (set.hoverZoom === "off") {
      $slider.addClass('hoverZoomOff');
    }

    // If titleBarTop is set to 'on' then move it up
    if (set.titleBarTop === "on") {
      $slider.addClass('titleBarTop');
    }

    // function to start auto play
    function startSlider() {
      sliderIntervalID = setInterval(function() {
        nextSlide();
      }, set.slidePause);
    }

    // on mouseover stop the autoplay
    $slider.mouseover(function() {
      if (set.autoPlay === "on") {
        clearInterval(sliderIntervalID);
      }
    });

    // on mouseout starts the autoplay
    $slider.mouseout(function() {
      if (set.autoPlay === "on") {
        startSlider();
      }
    });

    //on right arrow click
    $slider.find("> .right").click(nextSlide)

    //on left arrow click
    $slider.find("> .left").click(prevSlide);

    // Go to next slide
    function nextSlide() {
      position = $slider.find(".show").index() + 1;
      if (position > size - 1) position = 0;
      changeCarousel(position);
    }

    // Go to previous slide
    function prevSlide() {
      position = $slider.find(".show").index() - 1;
      if (position < 0) position = size - 1;
      changeCarousel(position);
    }

    //when user clicks slider button
    $slider.find(" > ul > li").click(function() {
      position = $(this).index();
      changeCarousel($(this).index());
    });

    //this changes the image and button selection
    function changeCarousel() {
      $slider.find(".show").removeClass("show").fadeOut();
      $slider
        .find("> div")
        .eq(position)
        .fadeIn(set.fadeSpeed)
        .addClass("show");
      // The Dots
      $slider.find("> ul").find(".showli").removeClass("showli");
      $slider.find("> ul > li").eq(position).addClass("showli");
    }

    return $slider;
  };
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="why">
  <div class="slider" id="slider1">
    <div style="background-image:url(https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF); background-color: #e0e1dd;"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000); background-color: #e0e1dd;"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://via.placeholder.com/150/00FF00); background-color: #e0e1dd;"></div>
    <div style="background-image:url(https://via.placeholder.com/150/000000); background-color: #e0e1dd;"></div>
    <i class="left" class="arrows" style="z-index:2; position:absolute;"><img src="cps-images/home-circle-left.png" id="lefticon"></i>
    <i class="right" class="arrows" style="z-index:2; position:absolute;"><img src="cps-images/home-circle-right.png" id="righticon"></i>
  </div>
  <script src="cps-js/nbi-home-promo-slider.js"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you also include `nbi-home-promo-slider.js`?

Comment: Can you provide a working jsfiddle?

Comment: You _might_ be able to just move the image to an `img` tag and wrap that in an `a` tag inside of the div like `<div style="background-color: #e0e1dd;"><a href="https://website.com"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF" /></a></div>`. But you might get some other weird layout effects from this. It's hard to tell without a full working example.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to the bottom of your page, before the `</body>` tag:

```
<script>
function visit(url){
    window.open(url, '_self');
}
</script>
```

Then you can add your links to the div like this:

```
<div style="background-image:url(cps-images/home-slider1a.png); background-color: #e0e1dd;" onclick="visit('https://www.google.com')"></div>
```

Comment: While this looks like it would work, it's not very accessible, so it should probably be redone using `<a>` tags

Comment: This solution worked great! Thanks! Accessibility isn't a concern. But one last thing, how do I get the cursor to turn into a "hand icon" when hovering over the image? Right now there's no visible indication that it is clickable.

Comment: You can change the cursor in the css: `<div style="background-image:url(cps-images/home-slider1a.png); background-color: #e0e1dd;cursor:pointer;" onclick="visit('https://www.google.com')"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Other solution would be to delete the background-images and just use regular "img" elements inside the "div" and then wrap them both inside "a" element.

In this case "img" should have the following styling:

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  }
```